# Get idle time in Windows 7 64 bit with VBA

Tags: vba

Simple (I hope) question: Is there a way to query the idle time of a Windows 7 64 bit PC with VBA? i.e., the time since anyone last moved the mouse or pressed a key

Context: I have a Rockwell FactoryTalk View SE application, which is a graphical control screen for a production line in a factory. The customer wants any logged in user to be logged out after 5 minutes. There's a setting for that in the software, so that's easy, the trouble is that when you log out, it basically closes the application until someone else logs in. Which means nobody can see anything. So what I want to do instead is, after a period of inactivity, log in a default user with view only privileges. The commands to log in and out are easy enough, it's just working out when to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a module:

```
Private Type LASTINPUTINFO
   cbSize As Long
   dwTime As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetLastInputInfo Lib "user32" (lii As LASTINPUTINFO) As Long
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Public Sub checkIdle()
    Dim idleSecs As Long: idleSecs = GetIdleSecs()

    Debug.Print "Idle for"; idleSecs

    'schedule next check
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "checkIdle", False
End Sub

Private Function GetIdleSecs()
    Dim lastInput As LASTINPUTINFO
    With lastInput
        .cbSize = Len(lastInput)
        Call GetLastInputInfo(lastInput)
        GetIdleSecs = (GetTickCount() - .dwTime) / 1000
    End With
End Function
```

Call `checkIdle` to start monitoring the idle time, add your condition by checking the resit of `idleSecs`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just for my understanding, what are the cbSize and dwTime objects? I can't use the OnTime command in this application, but I think I have another way around it.

Comment: Also, does this take into account the tick count "wrapping"? I've read elsewhere that this value wraps every 45 days or something. If this occurred, what would be the effect on this code?

Comment: GetLastInputInfo() uses the tick count itself to remains in parallel with GetTickCount()

Comment: LASTINPUTINFO is documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646272(v=vs.85).aspx